# Is there a way to run gsutil as a regular Linux cronjob on GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil, google-cloud-scheduler

I have a script that does some stuff with `gcloud` utils like `gsutil` and `bq`, eg:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

bq 'SELECT * FROM myproject.whatever WHERE date > $x' > res.csv
gsutil cp res.csv gs://my_storage/foo.csv
```

This works on my machine or VM, but I can't guarantee it will always be on, so I'd like to add this as a GCP cronjob/Lambda type of thing. From the docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating), it looks like the Cloud Scheduler can only do HTTP requests, Pub/Sub, or App Engine HTTP, none of which are exactly what I want.

So: **is there any way in GCP to automate some `gsutil` / `bq` commands, like a cronjob, but without my supplying an always-on machine**?

Comment: 1) Tools such as `gsutil` have requirements for the User Environment which include Python, Environment variables, Service Accounts, etc. 2) Cron jobs do not setup User Environments. The jobs run as a privileged process 3) This means you should redesign what you are trying to do so it fits within the scope of Cron Jobs or you will have to emulate a user environment for `gsutil`. Review this answer on options to specify a username to run a command under: https://serverfault.com/questions/352835/crontab-running-as-a-specific-user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are likely going to be multiple answers and this is but one.

For me, I would examine the concept of [Google Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/).  The idea here is that you get to create a Docker image that is then instantiated, run and cleaned up when called by a REST request.  What you put in your docker image is 100% up to you.  It could be a simple image with tools like gcloud and gsutil installed with a script to run them with any desired parameters.  Your contract with Cloud Run is only that you consume the incoming HTTP request.

When there are no requests to Cloud Run, there is no charge as nothing is running.  You are only billed for the duration that your logic actually executes for.

I recommend Cloud Run over Cloud Functions as Cloud Run allows you to define the environment in which the commands run ... for example ... availability of gsutil.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it could work for me. How would I then activate it? Would I use a GCP cronjob to send an HTTP GET request?

Comment: There is a GCP product called Cloud Scheduler that is basically serverless cron.  You get to define schedulers when things should be triggered.  When a trigger is to fire, Cloud Scheduler provides a number of targets ... including HTTP.  This means that we can use Cloud Scheduler to initiate a Cloud Run instance.